# Why does is_constructible claim something is constructible when it isn't?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, constructor, type-traits

The following program, when compiled with either GCC 4.7 and clang 3.2, produces "1" as output.

```
#include <type_traits>

struct foo {
    template<typename T>
    foo(T) {
        static_assert(not std::is_same<int, T>(), "no ints please");
    }
};

#include <iostream>    
int main() {
    std::cout << std::is_constructible<foo, int>();
}
```

This is confusing. `foo` is quite clearly not constructible from `int`! If I change `main` to the following, both compilers reject it due to the static assertion failing:

```
int main() {
    foo(0);
}
```

How come both compilers say it is constructible?

Comment: You should rather use enable_if to remove ints from the possible foos.

Comment: Here is another example, where `is_constructible` reports `true`, but the construction is impossible: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/c7ccK3onT

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is what the standard has to say (§20.9.5/6), with my emphasis:

> Given the following function prototype:
>
> ```
> template <class T>
> typename add_rvalue_reference<T>::type create();
> ```
>
> the predicate condition for a template specialization
>   `is_constructible<T, Args...>` shall be satisfied if and only if the
>   following variable definition would be well-formed for some invented
>   variable `t`:
>
> ```
> T t(create<Args>()...);
> ```
>
> [ *Note:* These tokens are never interpreted as a function
>   declaration. *—end note* ]
>
> Access checking is performed as if in a context unrelated to `T` and
>   any of the `Args`. **Only the validity of the immediate context of the
>   variable initialization is considered.** [ *Note:* The evaluation of the
>   initialization can result in side effects such as the instantiation of
>   class template specializations and function template specializations,
>   the generation of implicitly-defined functions, and so on. Such side
>   effects are not in the “immediate context” and can result in the
>   program being ill-formed. *—end note* ]

The assertion only fails when the template constructor is instantiated. However, as cleared up in the note, that assertion is not in the immediate context of the variable definition that is considered, and thus does not affect its "validity". So the compilers can count that definition as valid, and thus claim that `foo` is indeed constructible from `int`, even if actually attempting to construct a `foo` from an `int` results in an ill-formed program.

Note that the compilers are also allowed to, instead of having `is_constructible` yield false, just reject the original program based on the assertion, even though neither one does.

Comment: Note that it only makes sense. `std::is_constructible<>` determines whether there is a constructor that takes the argument, not that the constructor is well defined. Consider that the definition of the constructor (and thus the `static_assert`) need not be visible to the compiler when processing the `is_constructible`. If you want that to kick in, use SFINAE to disable that constructor for `int`, or alternatively add `foo(int)=delete;` which will mark the constructor as not available (not 100% sure of this last approach, but it should work)

Comment: Could you please explain your claims that implementations are 1) allowed to have `is_constructible` yield false and 2) are allowed to reject the original program?

Answer (score 5):

`foo2` is your `foo`.  `foo1` is a foo that does what you want your `foo` to do.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

struct foo1 {
  template<typename T,typename=typename std::enable_if< !std::is_same<int, T>::value >::type>
  foo1(T) {
    static_assert(not std::is_same<int, T>(), "no ints please");
  }
};
struct foo2 {
  template<typename T>
  foo2(T) {
    static_assert(not std::is_same<int, T>(), "no ints please");
  }
};

#include <iostream>    
int main() {
  std::cout << std::is_constructible<foo1, int>();
  std::cout << std::is_constructible<foo2, int>();
}
```