# Correct way to make is_copy_constructible for container yield false if underlying type is not copy constructible

Tags: c++, c++11, copy-constructor, type-traits

This is a follow-up to [std::unordered_map<T,std::unique_ptr<U>> copyable? GCC bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25803403/3959454)

So imagine we created a template class `Container`:

```
template<class T>
class Container {
    T t;
public:
    Container() = default;
    Container(const Container& other) : t(other.t) {}
};
```

Unfortunately, `is_copy_constructible` for it yields `true` even if `T` is not copy constructible:

```
static_assert(!std::is_copy_constructible<Container<std::unique_ptr<int>>>::value, "Copyable");
```

This assert fails for the reasons described in the answer to question above, also [here is another answer on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14815999/3959454).

It appears that this can be fixed by making the copy consructor template like this:

```
template<class T>
class Container {
    T t;
public:
    Container() = default;

    template<typename U = void>
    Container(const Container& other) : t(other.t) {}
};
```

This works in both GCC and clang (`static_assert` doesn't fail anymore).

[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/z3X0vG)

**The questions:**

1. From the viewpoint of standard, is this a correct way to make `is_copy_constructible` work? If yes, how does adding the template affect *the validity of the immediate context of the variable initialization* (`§20.9.4.3/6`)?
2. (optional) Are there any more correct or more intuitive ways to do this?

Note: declaring copy constructor `default` also achieves this objective, but is not always possible.

**UPDATE:** Now I see that my solution is invalid because copy constructor cannot be template. That still leaves room for question 2.

**UPDATE 2:** I changed a bit the code from [ecatmur's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25809914/3959454) to move ugliness out of `Container` itself and make it reusable:

```
struct unused;  // forward declaration only
template<class Container>
using const_ref_if_copy_constructible = typename std::conditional<
        std::is_copy_constructible<typename Container::value_type>::value,
        Container const&,
        unused>::type;

template<typename T>
class Container {
    T t;
public:
    typedef T value_type;
    Container() = default;

    Container(const_ref_if_copy_constructible<Container> other) : t(other.t) {}
    Container(Container&& other) : t(std::move(other.t)) {}
};
```

[(Demo)](http://ideone.com/B7TFmr)

But still I'm not quite satisfied with this. For me it looks like a flaw in C++ standard that such things don't work out of the box.

Comment: Be aware that "make the copy ctor a template" should not really work - an instantiation of a function template is never considered a copy ctor, so the compiler should add one if all you provide is the template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not doing what you think; a template constructor is never considered to be a copy constructor, so by adding `template<typename U = void>` to the copy constructor you're inducing the compiler to create its own default copy constructor.

A possibility (short of having separate class templates for non-copy-constructible types) would be to disable the copy constructor by replacing its argument with something that will be irrelevant for overload resolution:

```
struct unused;  // forward declaration only

template<typename T>
class Container {
    T t;
public:
    Container() = default;

    Container(
      typename std::conditional<
        std::is_copy_constructible<T>::value,
        Container const&,
        unused>::type other)
      : t(other.t) {}

    Container(Container&& other) : t(std::move(other.t)) {}
};
```

Comment: And this can be encapsulated so the code of container itself is not so ugly http://ideone.com/B7TFmr

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly an answer, so much as a detailed comment: One of the benefits of [Concepts Lite](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N4040.pdf) is the ability to constrain functions without requiring them to be templates as is the case with SFINAE. Concepts Lite will make this problem trivial:

```
template <typename T>
concept bool Copyable = requires(const T source, T dest) {
  T{source};     // copy construction
  dest = source; // copy assignment
};

template <typename T>
class Container {
  T t;
public:
  Container() = default;
  Container(const Container& other)
      requires Copyable<T>
    : t(other.t) {}
};
```

Comment: That's nice, but doesn't it actually create a function template, just using a simpler syntax?

Comment: @BenVoigt No, that's a plain old non-template member function declaration. You are thinking of function declarations that use a concept name or `auto` in the place of a parameter type (*generic functions* in the lexicon of concepts Lite), e.g., `void f(Copyable c);` or `auto f(auto& x) { ... }`, which do in fact declare function templates.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to ecatmur's answer is the following idea, where you derive from a templated base class that is either copy constructible or not depending on the template parameter.

```
template<bool> struct copyable {};
template<> struct copyable<false>
{
  copyable() = default;                  // default constructible
  copyable(copyable const&) = delete;    // but not copyable
};

template<typename T>
class container
  : copyable<std::is_copy_constructible<T>::value>
{
  T t;
public:
  container() = default;
  container(container const&) = default;
};
```

Note that for this to work, i.e. for `std::is_copy_constructible<container<std::unique_ptr<int>>>::value==false`, the copy constructor of `container` must be `default`.

Comment: This doesn't work if copy constructor of `container` is not default: http://ideone.com/hJcIFq

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I'll amend the answer to point that out.

Comment: And if copy ctor is default, it's actually not needed, as I noted in the question. See http://ideone.com/9h6dFx